# Find the degree of the normal closure $E$ of $F$ over $\mathbb Q$. What is the degree of $E$ over $\mathbb Q$?

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field, galois-extensions

My attempt:

The normal closure of $E/F$ implies $E/F$ is a normal extension of $F$ over $\mathbb{Q}$. Since the characteristic of $\mathbb{Q}$ is 0, then $\mathbb{Q}$ is a perfect field and every polynomial over $\mathbb{Q}$ is seperable, and so $E/\mathbb{Q}$ is a Galois extension.

I see that the proceeding is fine; but then I have no idea where to go after this. I tried to show that since normal extensions correspond to normal subgroups of the Galois group, then we can assume the degree of $[E:F]=2$ then the index of the corresponding normal subgroup $H$ is $[G:H]=2$.
But at this stage I feel like I am headed in the complete wrong direction.
Hints?

Comment: I don't think we can answer this question unless you tell us what $F$ is...

Comment: Yes I also thought that it lacked enough information to be solved but my instructor explained they were just generalized field extensions

Comment: So $E$ is the normal closure of $F/\Bbb{Q}$, or what? You have to specify the base field for *normal closure* to be meaningful.

Comment: What I'm saying that my expectation would be that the normal closure of $E/F$ is a minimal extension $M$ of $E$ with the property $M/F$ is normal. You seem to imply something different. Also, I agree with Alex Wertheim, something is missing. Or may be an answer in terms of $[F:\Bbb{Q}]$ and $Aut(F)$ is expected?